# rviz robot model error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

when I run the RVIZ, i have all these error in the left side **[ global status( fixed frame ) ] and [ robotModel(status :error..) ]**  and i'm trying to make a path for the robot to follow it but i can't make the robot move .

I would really appreciate your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216229/rviz-robot-model-error/) by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using amcl or gmmaping??
To see something chose, base_footprint on fixed frame of global options, to see the robot.
If you using  amcl or gmmaping  you must had map on fixed frame.

---

Originally posted by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) with karma: 66 on 2015-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-20**:
Thank you for your reply , I'm not using amcl or gmmaping , i found the package for both but i dont know how to make one of them work .

**Comment by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) on 2015-08-21**:
what robot are you using? try to do the tutorials of turtlebot (but in gazebo, that is a simulator), I learn a lot about navigation (moving robot, planning a path) doing that tutorials.

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-21**:
can you please give me the link to the tutorials
Thank for your time

**Comment by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) on 2015-08-21**:
http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot
instead of using the turtlebot_bringup packages use turtlebot_gazebo to launch the robot on simulator gazebo (ros already come with gazebo).
The mobile base of turtlebot is the kobuki base. Study how turtlebot and kobuki work, and you learn a lot.

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-21**:
I truly appricte your time and help , it's hard to find people like you
Thank You soo much